# как устанавить cookies из серверного компонента

Tags: nextjs

```
export default async function Home() {
  const res = await method();
  return <main></main>;
}

const method = async () => {
  const { cookies } = await import("next/headers");
  const value = cookies().get("some-cookie");

  const res = await fetch("/somewhere", {
    headers: {
      Cookie: `${value}`,
    },
  });

  // в res новые куки

  //как добавить новые куки к ответу от сервера next????

  return res;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил следуюшим образом.

любой fetch запрос при 401 кидает на route где идет отдельный запрос обновляюший пару токенов на беке и редиректит обратно на ту страницу где был запрос.